# Ajax results in 500 Internal Server Error because of large JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a the following code

ajax call

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
async: false,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url: "Account/SomeFunc",
data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),

success: function (res) {
//some code

},

error: function (res, textStatus, errorThrown) {
//some code

}
});
```

and on the server-side

```
public ActionResult SomeFunc()
    {
        //some code
        VeryBigObject result = getResult();

        if (result == null)
            return null;

        var jsonResult = Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;

        return jsonResult;
    }
```

result variable can be small but sometimes its a very big object. when the object is small enough the code works and the ajax success code is activated but when the result is big enough the code fails with 500  Internal Server Error.
I cant put MaxJsonLength any bigger because its an int but sometimes I need to send some big data.. what can I do?

Comment: You need to check your server configuration max_post_size and increase it.

Comment: Increase the `maxAllowedContentLength` in the `web.config` file. However, the default limit is 4Mb IIRC and you really, *really* shouldn't be sending that much JSON in a single request

Comment: This answer may helpful 
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/1151993/4611027

Answer (score 2):

Use the code below in `web.config`. It will solve your problem.

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="900000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
 </system.web.extensions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Increasing maxJsonLength in Web config worked for me when I faced similar issues with large json data.